# Why can I not access this JS object's props in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm debugging some code, and have boiled my problem down to this one simple example:

```
(js/console.log (.-hey (clj->js {:hey "please work!"})))
```

prints `undefined`

It must have something to do with renaming during advanced optimizations, but I can't figure out what's going on, nor how to fix it...

If you use an online CLJS REPL, like http://clojurescript.net/, it works as expected (returns `nil` but prints `please work!`), but under advanced optimizations using `cljsbuild`, it doesn't work at all!

Hrmm, any idea where I'm botching this up?

**Edit:**
Upon further reflection, and some advice from clojurians on slack, this is because the optimization mangles the keywords, I think, when I use `clj->js`.

I find that I (think) I need to do this though since I'm trying to interop with the D3.js library (from cljsjs), and when I pass it things, it's expecting `js` objects, not `cljs` objects. Is there an idiomatic way of passing in cljs objects to a js library that you're interoping with? (If that is indeed my problem?)

Comment: Hmmm have you tried (aget (clj->js ...) "hey") or #js {"hey" ...?

Comment: Check out http://cljsjs.github.io/ for externs for D3.

Comment: @TimothyPratley I think that would work, but I ended up changing the map to a vector/array, since indexes don't get mangled, and I'm using `aget` for the index of the vector. That works too, thanks for the response!

Comment: Good thinking! Glad you solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code won't work when compiled with advanced optimizations. You can check it comparing versions compiled with different optimization settings.

The part producing JS object works correctly, e.g. following will work:

```
(.log js/console (clj->js {:hey "please work"}))
```

will produce

```
Object {hey: "please work"}
```

But the part accessing `hey` property will break during compilation with advanced optimizations.

When you compile

```
(.log js/console (.-hey (clj->js {:hey "please work"})))
```

you will get something similar:

With `optimizations :none`:

```
console.log(
  cljs.core.clj__GT_js.call(
    null,new cljs.core.PersistentArrayMap(null, 1,
      [new cljs.core.Keyword(null,"hey","hey",301812684),"please work"], null)
  ).hey);
```

With `optimizations :advanced`:

```
console.log(Tg(new jb(null,1,[Nh,"please work"],null)).ci);
```

Notice how the `.hey` property key got mangled into `.ci`. This is because Google Closure renamed it during the optimizations phase (to save space in the result JS file it replaces names with shorter identifiers). `"hey"` string in your object won't get mangled as it's a string literal and you get the inconsistence.

When you pass the result of `clj->js` to an external function (e.g. in d3js) your code should work as expected as the external library won't be mangled if you use minified version with externs file (see @Andre's comment to your question and [CLJS doc about deps and externs](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Dependencies#external-javascript-libraries).)

When you need to access such properties like in your examples and need it to work with advanced optimizations you can use [`goog.object/get`](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.object.html#get) or [`goog.object/getValueByKeys`](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.object.html#getValueByKeys) as described in [`cljs.core/aget` doc](http://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/aget).

Comment: Great advice. Also, here's another solution (similar) that I ended up going with:  I ended up changing the map to a vector/array, since indexes don't get mangled, and I'm using `aget` for the index of the vector. That works too, thanks for the response!

Comment: I would like to add that the proper closure compiler way to take care of this is `goog.object/get` or `goog.object/getValueByKeys`, and `aget` is [considered incorrect](http://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/aget) unless working directly with arrays.